# Priority address list when retrieving companies

Tags: sql

I have an SQL problem that I'm struggling to get my head around. Consider these two tables with this data:

companies:

```
|    id    |    name    |
|     1    |Fake Company|
```

company_addresses:

```
|   id    |    company_id    |    name    |    address1    |    address2    |    town    |    postcode    |    main
|   1     |         1        | Head Office|   Building 2   |   RandStreet   |   London   |    L1 2FN      |     t
|   2     |         1        |    MAIN    |   Building 14  |   RandRoad     |   London   |    L1 6RR      |     f
```

I want to retrieve a company along with their main address. A main address is indicated by the `main` column being true in the `company_addresses` table. However, the data is somewhat messed up and some addresses are just called `MAIN`. Some companies don't have any addresses at all!

So, how do I retrieve a company and their address first choosing the address that's marked as `MAIN`, then if that doesn't exist get the address that's called `MAIN` and if that doesn't exist return nothing at all? All I have at the moment is:

```
SELECT * FROM companies c
JOIN company_addresses ca ON ca.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'Fake Company'
AND ca.main IS TRUE
```

but obviously that only brings back companies that have an address marked as main, rather than using the priority list I want.

Comment: Which database server are you using? It might matter.

Comment: If you tag it as such, it's more likely to be picked up by someone who follows the postgres tag(s), and will hopefully get you better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM companies c
JOIN company_addresses ca ON ca.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'Fake Company'
AND ((ca.main IS TRUE) OR (ca.main IS FALSE AND ca.name = 'MAIN'))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That accounts for a companies address being marked and named as main, however what if the company has no address whatsoever?

Comment: Add the condition in another `OR`. I didn't understand what you wish to return if no address found

Comment: I don't want to return anything if no address is found. I think I solved it with this: `(ca.main IS TRUE) OR (ca.main IS FALSE AND ca.name = \'MAIN\') OR (ca.main IS NULL)`

Comment: Ok, if you saying so. I thought `ca.main` is a NOT NULL column which should be either TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Well, some companies don't have a record at all in `company_addresses`.

Comment: Oh, so you want to return those companies as well? If so, just replace the JOIN by a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But I doubt that will make any difference as you're retrieving only columns of `companies` table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Postgres - but this might be useful as a general outline:

```
SELECT * FROM companies c
JOIN company_addresses ca ON ca.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'Fake Company'
AND (ca.id IS NULL OR ca.id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM company_addresses WHERE company_id = c.id ORDER BY main DESC, CASE WHERE name = MAIN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC))
```

This might not be the fastest solution, but it's reasonably simple, using a correlated subquery and TOP.